# How to set & write the magento_umask file in the directory file system?

Tags: adminhtml, permissions, magento-2.2.1

I'm sorry I am a beginner. I installed the last release Magento 2.2.1 on a shared hosting platform called OVH.

All the installation has been a 100% success. But now, I am facing permission & write files issues, which, on the backend don't allow me to click on the sidebar menu icons.

I created a magento_umask.txt but I don't understand exactly how to create, what format, and what to write inside it.

Can someone know?

Thank you a lot

Comment: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/post-install-umask.html

Chech this is magento official documentation for umask.

Comment: I know and I did but maybe I did it wrongly. no result.